# UI of fragment not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to call a fragment from my activity. The onCreate and onCreateView methods are being called. However, the UI for the fragment is not being displayed. I don't see any errors in logcat either.

Basically this is what I want to do. Upon clicking the imagebutton in activity.xml, I call the fetchNotifications() method, which in turn calls an asynctask to do some work and then call my fragment. In my fragment, I create a dynamic listview containing multiple textviews.

Here are my codes:

activity_home_screen.xml (my activity layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:src="@drawable/read_msg"
        android:onClick="fetchNotifications"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeScreen.java (my activity class):

```
public class HomeScreen extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    }

    //Method called from button onClick
    public void fetchNotifications(View view){
        new FetchNotifications().execute("http://x.x.x.x:9000/Android/homescreen/ruby");        
    }

    private class GetNotifications extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{//some code here}

    private class FetchNotifications extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        FragmentManager fm;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL notifications = new URL(params[0]);
                //JSONObject notificationsJSON = new JSONObject(getResponse(notifications).toString());
                JSONObject notificationsJSON = new JSONObject(globals.JSONS.NOTIFICATIONS);

                if(notificationsJSON!=null){
                    Globals globals = Globals.getInstance();
                    globals.setReplyString(notificationsJSON.getJSONArray("notification").toString());
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.add(new DisplayNotifications(), "Notification");
                    ft.commit();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public StringBuilder getResponse(URL url){//some code here}


}
```

activity_display_notifications.xml (my fragment_layout):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.buildingcustomadapter.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/notifications_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

single_notification.xml (contains textview which will be added to the listview):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally my fragment class (DisplayNotifications.java):

```
package com.example.projectswipe;

import globals.Globals;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayNotifications extends Fragment {

    Globals global;
    JSONArray notificationsArray;
    ArrayList<String> notification = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView l;

    public DisplayNotifications() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.d("Test", "onCreate >>>>>>>>");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_notifications, container, false);
        Log.d("Test", "onCreateView >>>>>>>>");
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            global = Globals.getInstance();
            notificationsArray = new JSONArray(global.getReplyString());
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>"+notificationsArray);

            for(int i=0; i<notificationsArray.length(); i++){
                notification.add(notificationsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("msg"));             
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        l = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.notifications_listView);     
        NotificationsAdapter adapter = new NotificationsAdapter(getActivity(), notification);
        Log.d("Test", "onActivityCreated >>>>>>>>");
        l.setAdapter(adapter);
        //l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        //l.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.emptyProductDeals));
    }

}

class NotificationsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context contex;
    ArrayList<String> notifications;

    /*
     * Create a constructor which calls super(). In super(), we pass context, the singlerow.xml file, and the datasource
     */
    NotificationsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> notifications){
        super(c, R.layout.single_notification, notifications);
        this.contex = c;
        this.notifications = notifications;
    }

    class MyViewHolder{
        TextView notification;

        MyViewHolder(View v){
            notification = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.notification_TextView);
        }

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View root = convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder = null;

        if(root==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) contex.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_notification, parent, false);
            holder = new MyViewHolder(root);
            root.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (MyViewHolder) root.getTag();
        }

        holder.notification.setText(notifications.get(position));

        return root;

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I know I'm missing something really basic, but I've been stuck at this thing for hours.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are missing the containerViewId - the container where you have to place the fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your main layout doesn't include a container (usually a FrameLayout) for your fragment and your FragmentTransaction doesn't specify where the fragment view must be attached. The `add()` method which doesn't take a containerViewId as parameter is reserved for fragments without a user interface, that's why you don't see anything.

Second, you can't call the FragmentManager from a background thread like you do here. It must always be done on the UI thread. If you use an AsyncTask, it means the FragmentTransaction must be done in `onPostExecute()` and not in `doInBackground()`. However, make sure your activity is started before you try to commit the fragment transaction or you will get an IllegalStateException. A common way to do this is to cancel the AsyncTask in `onStop()`, so `onPostExecute()` won't be called after `onStop()`.

Other potential problems in your code:

- Never set the height of a ListView to wrap_content. It may cause glitches and performance problems. Use match_parent, a fixed height, or a weight instead.
- Pass the data that your Fragment will show in its Arguments Bundle, or make the Fragment load its own data when it is shown, instead of loading the data in some global variable that your fragment will access later on. Your Fragment cannot rely on the fact that the global variable will be properly set when it starts because the system may kill your application at any moment when it's not visible and restore it later. When the application is restored, the Activity, the Fragment and its arguments bundle will be restored as well, but your global variable will not.

Comment: Just one more question. The fragment's UI is overlapping with that of the activity. How do I remove the activity UI?

Comment: Fragments are designed to be portions of activities. If you want your list fragment to be the single visible thing, either create a main fragment with your button that will be present at startup and replace it later with the list fragment, or launch a new Activity which contains the list fragment (if you want the user to be able to go back to the button).